# Test value of Angular 2 Observable for giving CSS class

Tags: angular, observable

I can display a value produced by an Observable using `{status_async | async}` in html.

However, how can I test whether this Observable is equal to something?

Specifically, I'd like to use it to assign a class:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'has-danger': status_async == 'created before'}">
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

I discovered that I can use:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'has-danger': (status_async | async) == 'created before'}">
```

But then the issue becomes that I have used async twice (here and for displaying the value).

As I'm checking the status of a succesful creation, ironically after the second async the value changes to 'created before', even when I clicked my create button only once.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: In your Observable use [`share()`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/share.md) to avoid subscribing twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be careful when using several async pipe on the same observable since this means that there are now several subscribers on it (the subscribe method is called several times, one per use of the async pipe).

In the case of an observable created from an HTTP call, the corresponding request will be called twice if subscribed twice)... By default such observables are cold (they can't be shared).

You need to make your observable hot using the share method:

```
this.status_async = this.status_async.share();
```

Comment: I'm `return`ing from `http.post.map()` and then in the view `{ status_async | async}`. I noticed `this.status_async = this.status_async.share();` doesn't work then anymore afterwards.

Comment: You set the return of the map method into the status_async property? Did you add the share operator like the map one?

Comment: Simply do the following: http.post(...).map(...).share(). This should work.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34677947/converting-angular2-http-response-to-connectableobservable/34678117?s=0|1.6248#34678117

Comment: To import the share operator: import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';

Comment: `this.status_async` is being set to the return  `this.http.post().map(request => "Created: " + request.json().created).share();`. Then when I want to `{{result}}` (instead of `{{result | async}}`) and it shows `[object Object]`. Previously it showed the string though.

Comment: How do set the result? Within a subscribe? I mean something like: `this.http.post().map(...).share(...).subscribe((data) => { this.result = data; });`

Comment: Sharing the observable shouldn't have impacts on the received data. I would be interested in the code you use to set the `result` property.